# Frequency limit for routing <32MHz digital signals adjacent to one another on different layers, 4 layer PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, spi, pcb-layers, trace

I'm running an 3.3V SPI device with an SPI clock frequency rated up to 10 MHz, with some additional digital outputs/inputs to/from a microcontroller that is clocked at 32 MHz.

Due to some space constraints I had to run three 10 mil traces adjacent to each other on 3 different layers as shown below, with 4 layers in total. They are partially adjacent to a grounded plane. Surrounding these traces, within about a 50 mil distance are also pads tied to a grounded plane.

The longest distance these traces are adjacent to one another is 181 mils or about 4.6 mm.
These traces are digital signals that are not the SPI communication lines.

At what frequencies would such a layout have problems due parasitic inductances and/or capacitances?

It seems like from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/345630/is-it-bad-to-run-traces-directly-over-each-other-on-separate-layers) anything below 100 MHz or "low frequency" and "low power" is unlikely to have problems, but I'm not sure if the same thing applies to this case of three traces of adjacent digital signals on different layers.

[image]

Comment: It is not possible to say without zooming out a bit.  Need to see more of the layout.  It's not about clock frequency so much as edge speed.  A 10MHz SPI clock, for example, might have a 5ns rise/fall time even though it has a 100ns cycle time.  The faster the switching time the greater the rate of change of current is (dI/dt).  This is turn is what governs the amount of noise the aggressor feeds into the victim.     Secondly, without knowing the victim signal's noise tolerance nobody can tell you whether this is going to cause you problems.

Comment: Finally it might work in terms of hitting your functional requirements but still fail emissions and/or susceptibility testing.  This is not uncommon.  A poor layout 'works' but generates lots of unwanted radiated or conducted emissions and you fail to get the product to market without respins, ferrites on cables, etc

Comment: @RobinIddon I believe the term for that is "slew rate". That is still helpful to consider, thanks.

Comment: Slew rate is V/s.  Rise time and fall time are the time it takes a logic signal to get from 10% to 90% or vice versa.  Of course they describe the same concept as one a other (rate of change) but slew rate more commonly used with opamps,.rise/fall time more commonly used with logic signals